# calling actionscript 3 function from javascript with addCallback not working

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, flash

I have a requirement in a project which has to call an actionscript 3 function from javascript. I read many answers from stackoverflow and adobe and have created a simple test application. In that, I have used ExternalInterface.addCallback to register both the functions and I've also included the security permissions in both actionscript and in html.

**Action Script 3 Embedded code**

*I did not use an external .as file instead i used the action panel to create the code.*

```
import fl.controls.Button
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

flash.system.Security.allowDomain("*")

var butt:Button = new Button();
addChild(butt);

butt.label = "hello";
butt.toggle = true;
butt.move(50, 50);
butt.height = 100;
butt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickhandle);

function clickhandle(e:MouseEvent)
{

        if(butt.height == 100)
            butt.height = 200;
        else butt.height = 100;

}

ExternalInterface.addCallback("callas", clickhandle);
```

The test app will display a ac3 button. Upon clicking that button it will toggle the expanding and collapsing of its height through a click handler 'clickhandle'. This is the function i am intended to call from javascript.

**HTML Code**

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function callas() {
    var hehe = document.getElementById('cvpanel');
    console.log(hehe);
    hehe.clickhandle();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p>Test</p>
<object id='cvpanel' name='cvpanel' width="425" height="350" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="one.swf">
    <param value="one.swf" name="movie">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"/>
    <p>You need Flash to see it.</p>
</object>
</body>
</html>
```

The application runs under http://localhost through apache and all the files needed are in the same folder. I could run the application and could see the buttons appearing. By clicking it they toggle in height as expected.

When i call the function callas from browser console i get the error in console as

> "TypeError: hehe.clickhandle is not a function"

in firefox and similar in Internet Explorer.

Is there anything missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In flash you're exposing *clickhandle* as *callas*

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("callas", clickhandle);
```

so you're supposed to call **callas()** from javascript

```
var hehe = document.getElementById('cvpanel');
hehe.callas();
```

Comment: I got an error msg in console like "Error calling method on NPObject!"

Comment: After searching for the above error i came across suggestions for a question which requested to follow certain rules. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607726/how-can-i-overcome-error-calling-method-on-npobject-and-play-a-swf . In this an user 'nuton' has suggested to call the function with exact parameters and if there are no parameters then the function should pass null. So, I called like hehe.callas(null) and it worked. additionally ...(contd)

Comment: I came across https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=308814 in which many users after doing systest they found that running the application from a real host(a live webserver)  works well. Yes, for me in the localhost it did not work even after adding null. I uploaded the flash file and the html file to my webserver and it worked. I followed only two conditions. One is passing null and the other is running the application from a webserver. and i did not follow the other suggestions.